# "Film motivates learners" or "the film motivates learners"

Tags: grammar

Do we have to use a definite article before *film* in the following example:

> Film motivates learners.

Or

> The film motivates learners.

Comment: Yes if you are referring to an individual film, no if you mean cinema in general.

Comment: @KateBunting Or if it's a newspaper headline to an article about a new motivational film.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to some special movie then use "The", else not needed.

E.g. I saw 'Pursuit Of Happiness' yesterday, loved it. The film motivates strugglers alot.

Comment: Many thanks, I understand that when we talk of film as a medium, or  to mean cinema in general we don't need to add 'the'.